# How to fully diagnose test environment issues in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

Rewriting original question since I will unlikely get an answer to the general one posted previously.

I added a new API namesapce in routes and a new API controller test.

```
namespace :api
  get "vehicles",    'to: "vehicles#index"
```

I already had an existing test for the frontend controller:

```
class VehiclessControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

and then added a new test file for the api controller:

```
class ApiVehiclesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

This is when the trouble began, and fixtures didn't seem to load. **Some did, other didn't.**

Renaming the api test class to:

```
class ApiVehiclesControllerTestNew < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

resolved the problem.

**Question: Where in the process flow is ApiVehiclesControllerTest create a name conflict with VehiclesControllerTest since rails seems pretty smart about everything else with the name space. Is it stripping off the Api at the beginning of the class name at some point?**

Comment: `bundle exec` ensures that the executable is run in the context of bundler (so that the correct gems are loaded). You can also run the bundler binstub by running `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails rails c`

Comment: Did you add new fixtures?  Do you have an existing fixture that has the same name as a new namespaced object. I have run into this it is when there is a bad fixture or introduced a name conflict and rails can't figure out what goes where.